# magento new order send mail not work in 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

When create a order mail not received Admin only received by user for order..
i try to change cron setting but not working yet..please give me answer is that default magento problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I upgraded my website to 1.9 version, I also faced the same problem where Order emails were not going.

There has been a change in the way emails are sent in 1.9.x version. After debugging on my deployment, I saw the error was related to mb_convert_encoding (lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php) was not defined and the method was not returning.

I installed php-mbstring and the issue was fixed. I used the following command to install php-mbstring

> yum install php54-mbstring

Comment: Thanx but not work still...customer get email but admin still not.

Comment: Can you try System-Configuration-Sales Emails from the Admin console ? And add the admin email in "Send Order Email Copy To".

Comment: yes i try it..but still facing same issue.

Comment: Any other idea about it?

Comment: Not sure. Can you try skip the cron job ? Copy app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
Modify Template.php and change $this->hasQueue() to !($this->hasQueue)

Comment: yes i do but getting only customer email not admin..

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the system.log ? Looks like admin notification does not work automatically. We can use the following article to install the extension: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-admin-order-notifier/

Comment: thanx for inchoo setup but i have another site in withoit inchoo order email sent..any other issue like server?

Comment: Doesn't look like since there are no errors and customer email is working fine.

Comment: ok..i think server problem..but confused because if server problem how get order mail customer?? then both not get mail na?